# VS2013 Project routing with both WebForms, MVC and Web-api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, visual-studio-2013

I use a new VS2013 project created with WebForms, MVC and Web-Api.

When using Aspx pages, they are displayed without .aspx extension.

Yes, I want to use MVC routing sometimes, and also aspx pages without any routing, but I would like to see .aspx extension.

Can I do that ? Thanks.

(In an old WebForms project I manually Added MVC fonctionnalities both webforms and mcv worked fine, so I think it's possible...)

Comment: Are those .aspx pages from the same MVC or an another project?

Comment: If VS2013 project holds both MVC and ASPX webforms, then without any changes to routes configuration, you can navigate to webforms with .aspx extension, and also by default MVC routes will work fine. So I am not able to repro the behaviour you mentioned in your question. Please add more information or at least repro steps.

Comment: Here is the scenario :


Run VS2013 Express   /   
File : New Project   /   
Web asp.net Application  : ADetruire02   /
Model : WebForms   /
Cheked : MVC + WebApi   /

New WebForm with master : MaWebForm with Site.Master   /
Adding some text in MaWebForm.aspx   /

Using URL : "http://localhost:59218/MaWebForm.aspx" displays    / "http://localhost:59218/MaWebForm"    /

Thanks

Comment: It's the same with a new WEBFORMS project created with visual studio 2013

Comment: It's OK now, I just uninstall FriendlyURLS nuget package.

Comment: We can also just comment routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings); in RouteConfig.cs file.